# Get shadow copies older than 5 days using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get these shadow copies that were created more than 5 days ago. How could I do this using PowerShell?

cmd> Diskshadow

Diskshadow> List shadows all

```
        * Shadow copy ID = {49fb469b-4940-45f7-98bd-08441e9e353c}
<No Alias>
                - Shadow copy set: {32224b82-e802-4eab-a903-fb5dc6558800}
<No Alias>
                - Original count of shadow copies = 11
                - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{bba82744-b690-4b68-9180-c0d81
7c5a38f}\ [G:\]
                - Creation time: 4/13/2021 6:03:34 PM
                - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeS
hadowCopy313
                - Originating machine: app.contoso.local
                - Service machine: app.contoso.local
                - Not exposed
                - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
                - Attributes:  No_Auto_Release Persistent Differential

        * Shadow copy ID = {8ac42987-5f9a-4535-aef0-c6d64d7a658b}



     * Shadow copy ID = {d9be01ee-c1e6-424f-ac9a-cf82ef4e5e58}
<No Alias>
                - Shadow copy set: {32224b82-e802-4eab-a903-fb5dc6558800}
<No Alias>
                - Original count of shadow copies = 11
                - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{1120d149-97e5-4b8d-af19-bb243
38626ef}\ [H:\]
                - Creation time: 4/13/2021 6:03:34 PM
                - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeS
hadowCopy271
                - Originating machine: app.contoso.local
                - Service machine: app.contoso.local
                - Not exposed
                - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
                - Attributes:  No_Auto_Release Persistent Differential
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that can do this:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CPolydorou.ShadowCopy/1.1.2/Content/ShadowCopy.psm1